rsa public key RSAKeyParser().parse error format
i generated rsa key pair in the nodejs side using this code:
const crypto = require('crypto');
    // Generate the RSA key pair
    const { publicKey, privateKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
        modulusLength: 2048,  // the length of your key in bits
        publicKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'pkcs1',      
            format: 'pem'
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
            type: 'pkcs1',     
            format: 'pem'
        }
    });

res.status(201).json({
message: 'Patient created successfully',
wallet: wallet,
rsaKeyPair: {
publicKey: publicKey,
}
});
then i sent the public key to flutter side then in the flutter side i am having trouble parsing the public key I have hard coded the public key:
var publicKeyString = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCE5COmhzUZLWHMW8FvgFG2QUdDmPvwOlvSHGrSV+asZOrVLzbwJQl0q3V0cZXyRR/j4YtwRI9x0z6nK25KfNDaGDMsgRiyqNil3dzE7c5QHd1CTC50RnDZnxztQBdNY3/WGFxBcF4WM2YtRqG5f10iSu0K5B7sX3k54bpMb0vHfQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
// Convert the keys from string to usable format
   final publicKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(publicKeyString) as RSAPublicKey;

i get error some sort of format error on this line.
i have tried fixing this error by changing the key format, but it didnt work

Use package:basic_utils.
This utility parses your string ok.
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:basic_utils/basic_utils.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';

RSAPublicKey _publicKey(String material) {
  return CryptoUtils.rsaPublicKeyFromDERBytes(
    base64.decode(
      material
          .replaceAll('\\n', '')
          .replaceAll('\n', '')
          .replaceAll('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '')
          .replaceAll('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', ''),
    ),
  );
}

Note that your key doesn't appear to have newline characters after the first and before the last line. If you add these (-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA... then you can use the shorter
final key = CryptoUtils.rsaPublicKeyFromPem(publicKeyString);

